# Loading custom forum posts: php echo vs. javascript.createElement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I built a custom forum for some friends a while back, and it's in dire need of a rewrite. As it is now, it grabs the posts' data from a mysql db and then echoes the data mixed into html when the page loads.

Simple example:

```
if ($inArray == true)
    echo '<div class="other">'.$reply.'</div>';
```

This seemed really messy to me, so I was planning on rewriting it using javascript to add elements to the dom. The more I think about it though, the more that seems like it would be a lot slower to use javascript.

My questions:

1. Would adding elements dynamically to the dom via javascript be
   noticeably slower than php echo for a small forum?
2. If so, is there a cleaner way to do it with php?
3. More generally speaking, is there a best practice for loading forum posts like this?

It may be worth noting that I currently have some code that loads new posts via AJAX, and plan on keeping this feature, so a viable solution would be friendly to auto updates.

As always I appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use AJAX. You could load a set number of posts on the initial load of the page and then use AJAX to load another bunch of posts on scroll or when a button is clicked.

Comment: Creating elements is rather fast, so for it to be slow you'd have to generate a lot of tags. Personally, I wouldn't use JavaScript for this, I'd keep it on the server side. I also don't see how the example method is "messy". The only other "cleaner" way would be using `printf()`: `printf('<div class="other">%s</div>', $reply);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is slow and adding to it with javascript is time consuming. I currently operate a website based on pulling info with ajax, creating a template for the data, and filling it in. I have not noticed a lot of slow down unless I'm drawing to the DOM to much in one function.

If your using $.html() you want to minimize the amount of times you use it.
For example, building a list dynamically (like in a loop ) you can add all your

```
  <li>Dynamic List Item</li>
```

to a var and then draw that with $.html() to reduce draw calls.

I'd recommend long polling your ajax requests, check for updates, and draw/update as needed by either updating the data, or clearing the changed data and drawing it all again.